# How to match single random node with multiple relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a newbie with this.  I have created a database of hundreds of proverbs and their MEANING, as well as Headwords and their definitions (MEANS).

I would like to generate a graph of a random Proverb, but with the related words and definitions.

My current cypher query that does return some interesting data looks as so:

```
MATCH p=()-[:MEANS]-(a:Headword)-[:USED_IN]-(d:Proverb)-[:MEANING]-()

RETURN p, rand() as r
ORDER BY r
LIMIT 1
```

I am getting a random Proverb, but the USED_IN and MEANS relations are also limited to 1.
I am wanting to produce something like below where there is a single Proverb and its MEANING (Orange), but there are relations to the words USED_IN (yellow), and the defintions (MEANS) of those words.   How can I attain that?

Just an FYI for the image below I bumped up the LIMIT in the cypher query to 3. But this may also produce 3 Proverbs etc.

[image: Desired graph sample]

Answer (score 0):

Try first fetching your `Proverb` node, and then the paths:

```
MATCH (d:Proverb)
WITH d, rand() as r
ORDER BY r
LIMIT 1
MATCH p=()-[:MEANS]-(a:Headword)-[:USED_IN]-(d)-[:MEANING]-()
RETURN p
```

Comment: Awesome!!   Thanks for putting me in the right direction!.   I did also have to add another LIMIT 10 after the RETURN p to get the multiple relations going.

Comment: @Boyd The second limit will basically ensure, that only 10 rows are returned. If there are more than 10 `USED_IN` relations, only 10 will be returned. Please make sure, if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cypher in this situation supports and requires an additional LIMIT parameter as so:

```
MATCH (d:Proverb)
WITH d, rand() as r
ORDER BY r
LIMIT 1
MATCH p=()-[:MEANS]-(a:Headword)-[:USED_IN]-(d)-[:MEANING]-()
RETURN p
LIMIT 10
```